# OpenVPN: Can't route to private network once connected to VPN tunnel

Tags: openvpn

I'm trying to setup an OpenVPN server to allow tunnelling to a private network (192.168.0.0/16) but when my VPN client is connected it cannot reach hosts on this network. No firewall is currently setup for the network/all ports are open. The server running OpenVPN is assigned the IP 192.168.0.2 on the private network

server.conf

```
local 1.2.3.4
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
server-ipv6 fddd:1194:1194:1194::/64
push "redirect-gateway def1 ipv6 bypass-dhcp"
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
```

client.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 1.2.3.4 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>
REDACTED
</ca>
<cert>
REDACTED
</cert>
<key>
REDACTED
</key>
<tls-crypt>
REDACTED
</tls-crypt>
```

Client connected to the OpenVPN server can ping the OpenVPN gateway as well as using its IP on the other subnet. However it can't ping a different host on the same network...

```
[26/10/21 19:58:32] user@client:~$ ping 10.8.0.1
PING 10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=27.3 ms
^C
--- 10.8.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 27.276/27.276/27.276/0.000 ms
[26/10/21 19:58:49] user@client:~$ ping 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=27.3 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 27.271/27.271/27.271/0.000 ms
[26/10/21 19:58:52] user@client:~$ ping 192.168.0.3
PING 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.3 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

OpenVPN server can ping a different host on the same network...

```
root@server:~# ping 192.168.0.3
PING 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.26 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.3 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.262/1.262/1.262/0.000 ms
```

OpenVPN server route table...

```
root@server:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
172.31.1.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 ens10
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ens10
```

192.168.0.3 routing table...

```
root@server:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 ens10
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ens10
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the routing on the hosts other than `192.168.0.2`. Also show the routing table on the system which is set to default gateway of those hosts (probably, `192.168.0.1`). Also, *never use `route`*, it's ancient, misleading and actually hard to read. Remove `net-tools` right away (by the way, Debian 10 and 11 already come by default without this packet, so it's certainly not essential). Always use `ip route` and other `iproute2` features, which is the proper way to configure and work with "modern" (circa 2000) Linux networking stack.

Comment: I'll spoil the thought: I suspect there is nothing wrong with path from 10.8.x.x to 192.168.0.x, but there are some problems in the reverse direction. It's reverse packets who can't be delivered, not forward.

Comment: Thanks @NikitaKipriyanov. I've updated my question with the routing table for 192.168.0.3. Point taken about using `ip route`. I'm not sure how to go about updating the routing table for hosts on the LAN for this configuration.

Comment: In general, you run a VPN service *on the router* who is, for example, the default gateway for some LAN. Or on the another router, but the thing which is gateway should have a dedicated route to the VPN through it. // And you were still using route. Kill this habit with fire, this is worse than smoking. Serously, Docker would be impossible without functionality of `ip route`, because the `route` utility doesn't know a thing about namespaces, upon which Docker is built. ifconfig, route, iptunnel, tunctl, brctl, vconfig — all of these were superseded and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The Internet Protocol looks only at the destination IP address when routing packets.  They do not care where a packet came from.  They do not care that the packet might be part of a larger session or connection or application.  The only thing that matters is the destination IP address.  IP then looks at the routing table to determine what to do with each packet, based solely on the destination address.  (Technically, things like statefull firewalls and policing routing can make this a lie, but it will do for current purposes.)

As @Nikita points out, and the output of `route(8)` shows, hosts like `192.168.0.3` (and, presumably, other hosts on your network) only know to send packets to your router at `192.168.0.1`.  They do not have anything to tell them to send packets to your OpenVPN system at `192.168.0.2.`.  So `.3` and friends will be sending all their traffic to your router.  Your router doesn't know about your VPN.  Your router will either discard the packets, or send them to the public Internet (where the next hop router will likely discard it).

The are multiple possible solutions.

#### Solution #1 - Easy But Inefficient

Tell your router that `10.8.0.0/24` is reachable via the gateway at `192.168.0.2`.  This will result in a hairpin route -- packets will go from hosts like `.3`, to your router's LAN interface at `.1`, and then back out the same router interface and to the OpenVPN gateway at `.2`.  This is inefficient, but should work.

You don't say what your router is, but if it was Linux, the command would be something like:

```
ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.2
```

#### Solution #2 - Unintrusive But Tedious

You can configure a static route on each LAN host, telling them the same routing tidbit as #1, but everywhere.  This would be a minor pain to configure and maintain, but would be the most efficient solution that keeps your existing network topology.  Same command as above (for Linux), but you have to run it on every LAN host.  You also need to do it on all other devices that should work over the VPN, including Windows boxes, printers, tablets, phones, wifi lightbulbs, etc.  You'll eventually forget one and wonder why it doesn't work, spend time pulling your hair out, and then feel like a dope when you remember why.

#### Solution #3 - Sophisticated But Disruptive

You can put your VPN gateway on the routing path to the Internet.  There are two sub-alternatives here.

##### Solution #3A - VPN On Router

Even consumer routers can sometimes run an OpenVPN implementation these days, especially if you use third-party firmware (OpenWRT, DD-WRT, etc.).  However they often lack the CPU horsepower for adequate performance.  You could also replace the consumer with something better -- a commercial router, or another Linux.  You might even be able to retask your VPN gateway as VPN+router+firewall.

In this scenario, the VPN and the router are the same thing, so you don't have to worry about the router getting along with the VPN gateway.  This is likely the most efficient, in terms of network design.

##### Solution #3B - Stack Gateway and Router

You can put the VPN gateway between the router and the rest of the LAN, with different IP subnets on either side of the VPN gateway.  All other LAN hosts send to the VPN gateway to get to the Internet.  The VPN gateway sends and forwards to the router to get to the Internet.

This will require putting two network interfaces in the VPN gateway -- one for the LAN, and one for the handoff to the rotuer.  (Or do a hairpin route on the VPN gateway, which is worse than #1 because now *all* Internet traffic is hairpinning).

The main advantages to this approach are: You can keep your existing router (maybe your ISP makes you use their equipment, maybe it has some other useful property for you).  If the VPN box breaks down, you can pull it out of the picture, and (maybe) quickly reconfigure the router to take its place.

Comment: Very helpful thank you

Comment: @MarkHingston: I'm glad you found this helpful.  If you need more help, please add specifics in a comment and/or revise your question.  If you consider your question resolved, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).